# React - How to remove space from left and right of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have space from left and right on the screen and I want to remove.

My ReactJS code:

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="one">
    <Nav variant="pills" defaultActiveKey="/home">
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link href="/home">Начало</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">Услуги</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="link-2">Услуги</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="link-3">Контакти</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Link eventKey="link-4">За Нас</Nav.Link>
      </Nav.Item>
    </Nav>
  </div>
  <div className="two"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
 .container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.one {
  width: 15%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  margin-left: 15%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("./Images/background.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

TIPS: When I remove this link from file public/Index.html:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

The display is stretch to the end of right and left (but I need it for react-bootstrap).

[image: Spacing from left and right side]

Comment: You need to inspect the element which is causing this space and then write a custom css to override the default margin or padding.

Comment: Also try to set "box-sizing: border-box" to container class